# pass parameters to bash script through npm run

Tags: bash, shell, npm, npm-scripts

I'm new to writting bash script and I have a npm package that I created
https://www.npmjs.com/package/comgen

**Bash**

```
days=3
hours=24
minutes=60
totalNumberOfCommits=3
lenghtOfTime=$((days*hours*minutes))
arrayOfCommits=$(shuf -i 1-$lenghtOfTime -n $totalNumberOfCommits | sort -r -n)

for index in $arrayOfCommits
  do
    randomMessage=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1)  
    git commit --allow-empty --date "$(date -d "-$index minutes")" -m "$randomMessage"
  done 
git push origin master
```

You run it like this **npm run comgen** I want it to run like this:

`npm run comgen -days "x number of days" -totalNumberOfCommits "x number of commits"`

Package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "comgen": "commit-generator.sh"
 },
```

Where the number of days and the total of commits passed will replace the number in the variables I have in the bash script.

I read this SO questions before postins my own: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32290/pass-command-line-arguments-to-bash-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how exactly `npm` works, but from my experience I guess that command-line arguments are passed directly to the called executable (binary or script). This means your script is actually called like

```
/path/to/comgen -days "x number of days" -totalNumberOfCommits "x number of commits"
```

Now it's pure Bash stuff to parse the cmdline arguments. You evaluate an option and decide what the next value is:

```
days=3
hours=24
minutes=60
totalNumberOfCommits=3

while [ $# -ne 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
    "-d"|"-days") days=$2; shift 2;;
    "-tc"|"-totalNumberOfCommits") totalNumberOfCommits=$2; shift 2;;
  # "-x"|"-xx"|"-xxx") : Process another option; shift 2;;
    *) break;;
  esac
done

lenghtOfTime=$((days*hours*minutes))

... rest of the code
```

Comment: All I have to do know is now go to pass variables to the npm run comgen -d 5 -tc 10

Comment: I got to the point where I can run this `commit-generator.sh -d 4 -tc 10` in the terminal. Now, when I want to do npm run comgen -d 5 -tc 10 i get `commit-generator.sh -d $1 -tc $2  "1" "10"` in my package.json I have `"scripts": {
    "comgen": "commit-generator.sh -d $1 -tc $2 "
  }`

Comment: i figured it out. My problem is that i need to pass the parameters with out the "-" and change the name in the bash script to be just d,tc,etc

Answer (score 2):

Try this

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "comgen": "commit-generator.sh"
 },
```

commit-generator.sh

```
 #!/bin/bash 
echo $npm_config_days
echo $npm_config_hours
```

and finally in terminal

```
npm run comgen --days=foo --hours=bar
```

output:

```
> commit-generator.sh

foo
bar
```